# Issue when I use ionic cordova run android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting an issue when I try to run with command line

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The error that it diplays is this one:

```
 ERR_NO_TARGET: No targets devices/emulators available. Cannot create AVD because there is no suitable API installation. Use --sdk-info to reveal missing packages and other issues.
```

But the thing is that I created a device in the Android Studio:

[image]

so I wonder what could the problem be? Thanks

Comment: did you trying running with --sdk-info  as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch the emulator and keep it running before executing the command `ionic cordova run android`

Click on the `Play` icon in the Virtual Devices list to launch the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer you're looking for but generally, I use:
*ionic cordova build android*
Then open the platform/android directory in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this :

for see avaliables devices this:

```
ionic cordova run android --list
```

for run android app on device this:

```
ionic cordova run android --device --verbose
```

i hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following variables set in your environment.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$HOME/.android/avd
```